# How do I rewrite a single category link to point to a custom page?

Tags: categories, url-rewriting

I have categories Cats, Dogs and Rabbits.

I would like to change the link used for "dogs" when listing category on the front end to a custom page instead of the category archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal seems to be to change the link which is output when listing the categories rather than making the existing link point to a different page as my last answer assumed. So I am going to try a different answer with a different solution.

Using the filter `term_link` in the function [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) you can change the link which is generated for a specific category.

```
function wpse_317747_filter_term_link( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( "category" !== $taxonomy || "dogs" !== $term->slug ) {
        return $termlink;
    }
    return get_permalink( $target_page_id );
}
add_filter( "term_link", "wpse_317747_filter_term_link", 10, 3 );
```

This changes the generated link if working on `category` taxonomy and the current term slug is `dogs`. Just set `$target_page_id` to correspond to the page you want the link to point to.

Comment: Thanks very much this solved my query! Unable to upvote due to newbie and low reputation myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I went ahead and added this code to my functions and changed $target_page_id to the desired ID and its return a blank page.

Comment: @DavidBarclay I just added two more arguments to the add_filter() call, as the filter function takes 3 parameters. If that was not the cause, you need to activate debug mode, to see the relevant error messages.

Answer (score 0):

For special behavior for a category, you can add a template file for the specific category. Such files are called [Taxonomy Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/). Creating the file ´category-dogs.php´ in your theme's directory will make wordpress load this file when the category with the slug ´dogs´ is requestd. As model for the new file you can copy the original ´category.php´ in your theme or just redirect the user to another existing page.

Comment: That won’t change the url which I’m also looking for.

Comment: Why are you even using categories if you don't want to use the URL _or_ template?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you display categories, you could create a menu where the link to Dogs is a page, instead of the category. 
Do you have posts in the Dogs category?

Comment: This would mean having duplicated content. I would only like some of my categories to use a custom page.